# Check 3rd party software version installed

Tags: wix

I'm filling property with installed office version

```
<Property Id="VISIOVERSION">   
                 <RegistrySearch Id="VisioVersion14x64"
                  Root="HKLM"
                  Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Visio"
                  Name="InstalledVersion"
                  Type="raw" Win64="yes" /> 
</Property>
```

How can I compare this version with a minimum version required? Versions look like `14.0.5432.3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If office version 14.0.5432.3 is minimum version required, try this condition.

```
 <Condition Message="Minimum office version 14.0.5432.3 is required to continue the installation.">
    (VISIOVERSION >= "14.0.5432.3")
 </Condition>
```

Answer (score 0):

A `LaunchCondition` should help out here. Checking that the prerequisite version is high enough is a simple `>=` operation. However, it is important to always include `Installed` in your `LaunchConditions` to ensure that your software can be uninstalled if the prerequisite was removed first. A full example:

```
<Condition Message="Viso v14.0.5432.3 or newer is required before installing [ProductName].">
  Installed OR (VISIOVERSION >= "14.0.5432.3")
</Condition>
```